# How to switch the mediaplayer to the next track automatically?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to switch the player to the next track automatically when the song is over, it automatically follows ringtone must reproduce. And the current time tunes should be output in the texеview
setOnCompletionListener -does not work, it does not go to the next track when the current is ended

//variables

```
        int[] soundsRawResIds = new int[]{R.raw.belarus, R.raw.russian, R.raw.japan,
            R.raw.litva, R.raw.england, R.raw.finlandia, R.raw.france};

    private final Handler handler = new Handler();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initViews();
        currenttime=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.timeSound);
        buttonPlayStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonPlayStop);

    }
    private void initViews() {
       mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, soundsRawResIds[0]);
        seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
        seekBar.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                seekChange(v);

                return false;
            }
        });
    }


    private void seekChange(View v){
        if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
            seekBar = (SeekBar)v;
            mediaPlayer.seekTo(seekBar.getProgress());


        }
    }
    public void playAndStop(View v){
        if (buttonPlayStop.getText() == getString(R.string.play_str)) {
            buttonPlayStop.setText(getString(R.string.pause_str));

                mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        index++;
                        mp.reset();
                        if (index < soundsRawResIds.length) {
                            try {
                                AssetFileDescriptor afd = getResources().openRawResourceFd(soundsRawResIds[index]);
                                if (afd != null) {
                                    mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
                                    afd.close();
                                    mp.prepare();
                                }
                            } catch (Exception ex) {
                                // report a crash
                            }
                        } else {
                            // done with media player
                            mp.release();
                            mp = null;
                        }
                    }
                });

                mediaPlayer.start();
                startPlayProgressUpdater();

        }else {
            buttonPlayStop.setText(getString(R.string.play_str));
            mediaPlayer.pause();
        }
    }
    public void startPlayProgressUpdater() {
        seekBar.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());

        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            Runnable notification = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    startPlayProgressUpdater();
                    if(seekBar.getProgress()==100){
                        for(int index=0;index<soundsRawResIds.length;index++){

                            index++;
                        }
                    }

                }
            };
            handler.postDelayed(notification,1000);
        }else{
            mediaPlayer.pause();
            buttonPlayStop.setText(getString(R.string.play_str));
            seekBar.setProgress(0);
        }
    }
}
```

My XML code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <SeekBar
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:progress="0"
            android:max="100"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/seekBar"/>
        <Button
            android:text="@string/play_str"
            android:textSize="15pt"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:onClick="playAndStop"
            android:id="@+id/ButtonPlayStop"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginRight="-3dp"/>
       <TextView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:id="@+id/timeSound"
           android:textSize="30sp"
           android:text="00:00"
           />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set an onCompletionListener to mediaPlayer.

```
mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
  @Override
  public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            //custom method to play next song
            playNextSong();        
  }
});
```

Playing from array simple example.

```
private String[] songPaths;
private int playingPostion=0;

public void play(){
   if(mediaPlayer==null){
      mediaPlayer=new MediaPlayer();
   }else{
      mediaPlayer.reset();
   }
   //your array contains resource files.First convert them to a uri before submitting to the mediaPlayer
   String uri = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/"+songPaths[playingPosition];
   mediaPlayer.setDataSource(Uri.parse(uri));
   mediaPlayer.prepare();
   mediaPlayer.start();
   //prepare your textviews and seekbar

   //prepare the player to play next song from array after completing current song
   if(playingPosition==0){
     if(songPaths.length>1){
        playingPosition++;
     }
   }else if((playingPosition+1)==songPaths.length){
        playingPosition=0;
   }else{
        playingPostion++;
   }

   mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    play();
                    //do anything else you desire
                }
            });  
}
```

The above code is as an example only. Use your threads and try catch statements properly.

Comment: i added this method but my song repeat when stopped.
I'm trying to listen to music from an array

Comment: you create new player MediaPlayer mp
erro -38

Comment: Your array contains resources. Convert them to a uri and then set it as thedata source. Updated the answer.

Comment: [link](http://pastebin.com/c8WJWFHN)
does not work, it does not go to the next track when the current is ended

Comment: I see you've added the method I wrote but I didn't see you called it anywhere. On your playAndStop(View v) you've used mediaPlayer.start(). What am I not getting here? Call play() instead of medaiPlayer.start(). You've to alter the rest of the code accordingly.

Comment: I edited the file you linked. See if it works. You can find it @ http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/hxT8QTeT

Comment: Many thanks!
when start еру projec i see:
Error occured , and project close

Comment: MediaPlayer: Error (-38,0)

Comment: I made one last update. Check it on the link i provided. Just work on it man. Put some logs and see where the error is coming. You cant expect the people here to completely debug your programme! I don't think it works like that. Any way keep me updated on what happens. Good luck.

Comment: @ Malith Lakshan
 
Many thanks! 
Many thanks! 
Many thanks!